# Script in bash that checks if service is running

Tags: bash

I tried to write a script that is waiting for a service to be running.

After testing many approaches I ended up with this:

```
until [ service docker status | grep "active (running)" ]
do
  service docker status | grep "active (running)"
  sleep 1
done
```

which does not work.
Could you help me to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try either

```bash
while true; do
  service docker status | grep "active (running)" >/dev/null && break
done
```

or

```bash
while service docker status | grep -v "active (running)" >/dev/null; do
  sleep 1
done
```

Notice the `-v` argument in the second snippet. That is to invert the condition, as in, if there's no match, it'll loop the `sleep`.
I also added a `>/dev/null` to prevent spamming from `grep`.